# Add class the OPTION selected

Tags: jquery

How can I add a Class to the HTML `<option>` that I have selected from HTML `<select>`, if for instance the markup is

```
<select>
  <option>value 1</option>
  <option>value 2</option>
</select>
```

I used the following jQuery code:

```
$('option').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('demo');
})
```

and also tried the `change` event. However, both seems to fail. Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

You have to bind the `change` event on the `<select>` element:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).find(':selected').addClass('selected')
           .siblings('option').removeClass('selected');
});
```